# GitHub file deletion

Tags: file, github

So I tried to use github for the first time ant I accidentally deleted my code, and I found what I can restore it, but I need to access my log. I tried typing this command git log --diff-filter=D --summary ,  but it returns fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Maybe you could help me

Comment: Clone your github repo again.

Comment: Did you delete your code locally?  Did you delete code, commit it, then push that to github?  Or did you delete your github repository?